# ¿Cómo unir columnas con el mismo nombre en una sola?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Tengo un xls con diferentes columnas con el mismo nombre, cuando lo exporto a con Pandas, a esas columnas me les agrega un número consecutivo antecedido de un punto:

> ```
>  a a.1 a.2 a.3 a.n b ... b.n  c ... c.n
>  4   2   5   4   3
>  1   2   3   4   5
> ```

lo que yo quiero obtener es

> ```
> a b c 
> 4 . . 
> 1 . .
> 2 . .
> 2 . .
> 5 . .
> 3 . .
> 4 . . 
> 4 . .
> 3 . .
> 5 . .
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
 df3 = pd.read_excel('data01.xls') 
 s2 = pd.read_csv('s2.csv', header=None) 
 s2 = s2[0].tolist() 
 df3.columns = s2 
 df4 = df3.groupby(df3.columns.values, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).sum().apply(pd.Series).T.sort_values('StudySubjectID')   
df4.to_excel('df4.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas no permite usar el mismo nombre para diferentes columnas en un mismo DataFrame, lo cual es lógico por otra parte. Por eso ante esta situación tiene dos comportamientos, o renombra la columna como en este caso o la sobreescribe.

No hay forma, al menos que yo conozca, de unir las columnas directamente durante la lectura del archivo. Lo que si podemos hacer es unirlas después.

Una posible forma de abordarlo es:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd


def joining_same_name_columns(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    cols = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for col in df.columns:
        k = col.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)[0]
        cols[k].append(df[col])
    
    join_df = pd.DataFrame({name: pd.concat(columns) for name, columns in cols.items()})
    join_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    
    return join_df
```

---

La idea es simplemente obtener las columnas con el mismo nombre gracias a separando por `.` desde la derecha gracias `str.rsplit` y agruparlas en un diccionario en el que la clave es el nombre de la columna y el valor una lista con las columnas que han de unirse. Después basta con usar `pandas.concat`.

Si tenemos un Excel como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ```
> >>> df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
> >>> df
>
>    a  a.1  a.2  a.3  a.4  b  b.1  b.2  b.3  b.4  c  c.1  c.2  c.3  c.4
> 0  4    2    5    4    3  8    7    2    2    4  7    8    2    7    4
> 1  1    2    3    4    5  1    5    3    0    3  5    8    6    7    1
>
>
> >>> df = joining_same_name_columns(df)
> >>> df
>    a  b  c
> 0  4  8  7
> 1  1  1  5
> 2  2  7  8
> 3  2  5  8
> 4  5  2  2
> 5  3  3  6
> 6  4  2  7
> 7  4  0  7
> 8  3  4  4
> 9  5  3  1
> ```

Obviamente esto puede fallar si las cabeceras contienen el carácter**`.`**. Ante esta situación tenemos varias soluciones, desde renombrar primero las columnas a leer la cabecera por separado por otro medio y usarla para construir el diccionario.

Comment: Gracias por responder my friend, he probado lo que me sugeriste y me devuelve este error, ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis, probe otra cosa teniendo en mente tus consejos y me resulto, lo que me queda trabajar en el orden y en el ID del sujeto, aunque creo no me va a ser importante, aca te mando el codigo: df3 = pd.read_excel('data01.xls')
s2 = pd.read_csv('s2.csv', header=None)
s2 = s2[0].tolist()
df3.columns = s2
df4 = df3.groupby(df3.columns.values, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).sum().apply(pd.Series).T.sort_values('StudySubjectID')
df4.to_excel('df4.xls')